# How to insert a URL into MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits information into a database.  The form includes 3 inputs - a name, a description, and a URL.  All three work fine and submit the data into the database, but the URL input only works if the text that is entered DOES NOT include `http://` which is not what I want. I NEED it to include the `http://`

Currently, if I submit the form without the `http://` it goes through fine, but if it does include the `http://` I get a 406 not acceptable error.

I've read some articles about `mysqli_real_escape_string` but I haven't had any luck getting it to work.  Currently I have the following:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$code_name = filter_var($_POST['code_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$code_desc = filter_var($_POST['code_desc'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$code_dest = filter_var($_POST['code_dest'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO qr_codes (code_name, code_desc, code_dest ) VALUES (:code_name, :code_desc, :code_dest )");

$stmt->bindParam(':code_name', $code_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':code_desc', $code_desc, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
$stmt->bindParam(':code_dest', $code_dest, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

$stmt->execute();
```

Here is the form:

```
<form id="newQR" method="post" action="create-qr-code.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
    <ul class="new-qr-form">
        <li><label>Name</label><br><input id="code_name" name="code_name" type="text" class="form-control" ></li>
        <li><label>Description</label><br><input id="code_desc" name="code_desc" type="text" class="form-control" ></li>
        <li><label>Destination</label><br><input id="code_dest" name="code_dest" type="text" class="form-control" ></li>
        <li class="img-src-preview"><label>Preview Source</label><br><input value="test" id="code_img_src" name="code_img_src" type="text" class="form-control" ></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Any ideas on why it won't allow a URL?

Comment: Are you using GET method in your form? can you post your form or how you're submitting the data to it? You're using PDO you don't need to use mysqli_real_escape_string and more over its a completely different library as you're using PDO and not MySQLi, you're already using prepared statements within your sample code which is just fine.

Comment: might need to urlencode the url?

Comment: I am using POST, I will insert my form above.

Comment: What datatype is using for this URL field and the MySQL version?

Comment: The data type is text, although I tried with URL as well, and MySQL 5.5 it looks like. (I'm restricted to GoDaddy)

Comment: Oh, im sorry, it's a varchar.  Thought you meant the input type.

Comment: 406 Not Acceptable? Sounds like something the underlying web server would produce, not a problem with PHP and/or MySQL.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the only time it occurs is if a URL is entered, it works if it isn't a URL, and that's when I got confused.  

I can also go into the database manually and change it to a URL.

Comment: May your web server be configured in some complicated way that may trigger this? Some IDS in front of it which is too aggressive filtering something? Is there any further code which is triggered only in response to your data being a full URL? Are the requests entirely identical otherwise (have you checked with a wire sniffer or network inspector)?

Comment: No, I removed what I thought could be causing the problem when I troubleshooted before posting. That code right there is it. I'm going to check with my hosting provider to see.

Comment: You need to describe the problem better. Is this occurring on form submission or mysql insert? Is any data inserted when this error occurs? etc. As mentioned above, this is an apache error and has nothing to with mysql.

Comment: No data is inserted, and it happens on submit.

Comment: That's because there's an apache mod rule blocking the request. Need to create a rewrite rule or contact your hosting company.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. What kind of rewrite rule is necessary for something like this?

Comment: So, I talked to my hosting provider, and this was their response:

I looked at the errors that are being generated. They are being generated because the server is detecting a potential remote file injection. You will need to review the code and, and may have to modify the way it functions. We are unable to bypass that kind of error.

Any suggestions on that rewrite rule or how I could modify the above code to make it function properly?

Comment: Option 1: Upgrade your plan to a dedicated server or a VPS. You must be on a shared hosting plan. Option 2: intercept form submission, encode your input on-the-fly (by the way, this is an ugly workaround to be used as a last resort only).

Comment: Perhaps you can strip the http:// out of the variable before it is saved, and restore it when the record is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to just remove the http:// onSubmit in validateForm() . Or you can encode it in some way, for example with encodeURIComponent().

Answer (score 0):

```
$url= filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

USE the FILTER_SANITIZE_URL-Constant for your URL